# Increase speed levels and spawn rate of each kind of Enemies after certain level

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a unity game script that I want to improve but my basic C terms are making errors.

I want to increase the amount of different Enemy sprites, and include 3 or 4 levels of difficulty by increasing speed and spawn rate for each kind of different enemy sprite after every 3 or 4 levels.

I used

```
public GameObject enemy;
public GameObject enemy2;
public GameObject enemy3;







// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Handle the back button on Windows Phone 8
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            HandleBackbutton();
        }

        spawnNewEnemyTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (spawnNewEnemyTimer <= 0)
        {
            spawnNewEnemyTimer = 5;


            int spawnNumberOfEnemies = 1 + (level/2);

            for (int i = 0; i < spawnNumberOfEnemies; i++)
            {
                GameObject enemyToSpawn;
                enemyToSpawn = enemy;

                if (level > 2)
                {
                    float rndEnemy = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
                    if (rndEnemy > 0.5)
                    {
                        enemyToSpawn = enemy;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enemyToSpawn = enemy2;
                    }
            else
            {
                enemyToSpawn = enemy3;                 //GIVING ME ERROR HERE
            }
                }

                float modifier = Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f) * 3;

                Instantiate(enemyToSpawn, new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + 20.0f + i * 3,
                       player.transform.position.y + modifier, 0.0f), Quaternion.identity);
            }

            float rndPowerupHp = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
            if (rndPowerupHp < 0.1)
            {
                Instantiate(hpPowerUp, new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + 30.0f,
                       player.transform.position.y, 0.0f), Quaternion.identity);
            }

            float rndBuilding = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
            if (rndPowerupHp < 0.5)
            {
                GameObject whatBuilding = building1;

                float rndWhatBulding = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);

                if (rndWhatBulding > 0.5)
                {
                    whatBuilding = building1;
                }
                else
                {
                    whatBuilding = building2;
                }

                Instantiate(whatBuilding, new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + 30.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.005f), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
```

But it's giving me errors.

Comment: It would be quite useful for solving errors to *actually post them*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more than likely caused by your improper indentation. This causes you to make an error where it concerns braces:

This section of code

```
            if (level > 2)
            {
                float rndEnemy = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
                if (rndEnemy > 0.5)
                {
                    enemyToSpawn = enemy;
                }
                else
                {
                    enemyToSpawn = enemy2;
                }
        else
        {
            enemyToSpawn = enemy3;                 //GIVING ME ERROR HERE
        }
            }
```

when properly indented looks like this:

```
if (level > 2)
{
    float rndEnemy = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
    if (rndEnemy > 0.5)
    {
        enemyToSpawn = enemy;
    }
    else
    {
        enemyToSpawn = enemy2;
    }
    else
    {
        enemyToSpawn = enemy3;                 //GIVING ME ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

That should make the error pretty obvious. You have a second `else` statement after your initial one. And that won't fly.

So make sure to always keep a check on your indentation. That will help you prevent or identify errors like this.

Comment: aaaa.. ,i have checked that and I know there's a second "else" statement. Although if you read my question right, you'll see that I have already mentioned my basic knowledge- "but my basic C terms are making errors". What I really meant to say here "//GIVING ME ERROR HERE"  That I want to spawn another kind of enemy using "enemy3" although since I'm not good in C, I can not make another condition, or do not know how to make another "else" statement that it also spawn another kind of enemies, when its spawning type 1 and 2 already. I wanna know what to use "elseif" "or" to allow one more spawn.

Comment: Its more of a Logic question. I wanna use "if" and "else" in a way that I can spawn all 3 kinds of enemies.  Should I do "if (level <=2 )" and "if (level <= 4)" and "if (level > 6)"    .....

Comment: Okay, first of all you're not programming in C, but in C#. Big difference. Secondly, the logic doesn't matter all that much if you haven't grasped the basics and the errors that lack of knowledge causes. First understand these basic language features, fix the errors and then work on your logic. Other than that, if you want something to happen each 3 or 4 levels, just check if the level number you're at is divisible by that amount without a remainder.

Comment: I was able to add new enemies, now i just ahve to figure out how, to increase enemy speed.  Can you tell me what does these mean - (   Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
    if (rndEnemy > 0.5)     )

Comment: So wait, this is not your own code? As for the rest, the documentation helps: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: no it came in a free kit,  i am using. Thanks for the link, i was searching for something like that, wiki does not help much